# Monitoring application endpoint in grafana

Tags: grafana, grafana-alerts

I have an endpoint which gives me output like below

`{"status":"UP","checks":{"database":"ok","migrations":"ok","cache":"ok"}}`

I can get the endpoint output in dashboard using `infinity` plugin.

[image: Infinity plugin Dashboard]

While trying to setup alert notification, data is not fetched.

[image: Alert notification]

Am I missing something here? or is there any other way to setup alert notification if the `status` is down ?